# Mat-sort is not working in angular mat-table

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

My mat-table is working fine, but when adding mat-sort following the official api documentation, it fails at the ngAfterViewInit with the following message

**Cannot set property 'sort' of undefined
 aq LeadsComponent.push../src/app/leads/leads.component.ts.LeadsComponent.ngAfterViewInit**

There is already a SO post on Mat-table Sorting Demo and tried them but I still am not able to get it working.

can some one hemp me solve this issue? The official example works with a "static" MatTableDataSourcedefined in the component itself, I am querying from my back-end, however.

MatSortModule is already imported in app.module.ts, mat-sort-header directives are applied to the columns and the ngAfterViewInit is already exactly like in the official example...

```
 export class LeadsComponent implements OnInit,AfterViewInit  {

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'leadStatus', 'mobile', 'email', 'actions'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<LeadsChildObject>;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, private dashBoardService: LeadsService,
    private toast: ToastrService) {
  }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.dashboardService.getFeedback.subscribe(
          res => {
            this.leadlist= res;
            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.leadlist);
          }
        );
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you initialize `this.dataSource`?

Comment: i updated my code please see now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Cannot set property 'sort' of undefined aq LeadsComponent.push../src/app/leads/leads.component.ts.LeadsComponent.ngAfterViewInit

This error refers to "sort" being called on an undefined property, which, after your update, is the datasource property, because you don't initialize it.

It is not initialized, because your `subscribe()` (where you initialize it) is **async**, therefore, the initialization happens **after** `ngAfterViewInit()` happens.

Please initialize it in your `ngOnInit()` with:

```
ngOnInit() {
  // This line of code below:
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<LeadsChildObject>();

  this.dashboardService.getFeedback.subscribe(
    res => {
      this.leadlist= res;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.leadlist);
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    }
  );
}
```

The problem in your approach ist, that you are mistaking the use of the `MatTableDataSource` with a plain array approach (Simple Table approach). Please find this [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#datasource) to implement the `MatTableDataSource` approach

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try this way:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dashboardService.getFeedback.subscribe(
      res => {
        this.leadlist= res;
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.leadlist);
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;  //new line, also remove same from viewinit
      }
    );
  }
```